# Diversos errores al compilar en C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Hola he intentado correr este programa con la librería cvBLOB, muy poco he tocado este lenguaje, espero me puedan ayudar, estos son los errores que me tira

```
g++ -Wall -o "blob" "blob.cpp" (en el directorio: /home/daniel/Descargas)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCestzE.o: en la función `main':
blob.cpp:(.text+0x5c): referencia a `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: blob.cpp:(.text+0x7a): referencia a `cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params::Params()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: blob.cpp:(.text+0x11e): referencia a `cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params const&)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: blob.cpp:(.text+0x13f): referencia a `cv::noArray()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: blob.cpp:(.text+0x216): referencia a `cv::drawKeypoints(cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: blob.cpp:(.text+0x27c): referencia a `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: blob.cpp:(.text+0x2a4): referencia a `cv::waitKey(int)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCestzE.o: en la función `cv::String::String(char const*)':
blob.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x54): referencia a `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCestzE.o: en la función `cv::String::~String()':
blob.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): referencia a `cv::String::deallocate()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCestzE.o: en la función `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
blob.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x28): referencia a `cv::String::deallocate()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCestzE.o: en la función `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
blob.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): referencia a `cv::fastFree(void*)' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCestzE.o: en la función `cv::Mat::release()':
blob.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x4b): referencia a `cv::Mat::deallocate()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Ha fallado la compilación.
```

y este es el programa que quiero compilar o el código que quiero compilar

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    // Read image
    Mat im = imread( "blob.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

    // Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

    // Change thresholds
    params.minThreshold = 10;
    params.maxThreshold = 200;

    // Filter by Area.
    params.filterByArea = true;
    params.minArea = 1500;

    // Filter by Circularity
    params.filterByCircularity = true;
    params.minCircularity = 0.1;

    // Filter by Convexity
    params.filterByConvexity = true;
    params.minConvexity = 0.87;

    // Filter by Inertia
    params.filterByInertia = true;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;


    // Storage for blobs
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;


#if CV_MAJOR_VERSION < 3   // If you are using OpenCV 2

    // Set up detector with params
    SimpleBlobDetector detector(params);

    // Detect blobs
    detector.detect( im, keypoints);
#else 

    // Set up detector with params
    Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);   

    // Detect blobs
    detector->detect( im, keypoints);
#endif 

    // Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    // DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures
    // the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

    Mat im_with_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints( im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS );

    // Show blobs
    imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints );
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que no ha enlazado todas las librerias de opencv. Puedes probrar compilando de esta forma.

```
g++ blob.cpp -o blob $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)
```

Un equivalente es llamar a todas las librerias disponibles de este modo.

```
g++ blob.cpp -o blob -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```